# Angular repetition of two rows instead of single row

Tags: html, css, angular

I need to have an `*ngFor` of table rows, where each repetition consists in 2 rows, as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pgschr/b1yc7oqv/).

But in Angular the repetition is done for each row, not each 2:

```
<table>
   <tr *ngFor="let row of rows; let i = index">
       <td>{{row.somethingA}}</td>
       <td>{{row.somethingB}}</td>
   </tr> 
</table>
```

What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always use an `ng-container`.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let row of rows; let i = index">
    <tr>{{ row.something }}</tr> 
    <tr>{{ row.somethingElse }}</tr> 
</ng-container>
```

Comment: The ng-container is not rendered in the DOM by angular, making it ideal for what you want to achieve